# Twitter Bootstrap thumbnail class not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm following the tutorial to YelpCampround! I'm on version v1 and the full code of the app is here:

YelpCamp Version1[1](https://ide.c9.io/learnwithcolt/webdevbootcamp)

Even copying and pasting the original code:

```
<% include partials/header %>
 <div class="container">
     <header class="jumbotron">
         <div class="container">
             <h1>Welcome To YelpCamp!</h1>
             <p>View our hand-picked campgrounds from all over the world</p>
             <p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="/campgrounds/new">Add New Campground</a>
             </p>
         </div>
     </header>

     <div class="row text-center" style="display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
        <% campgrounds.forEach(function(campground){ %>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                   <img src="<%= campground.image %>">
                   <div class="caption">
                       <h4><%= campground.name %></h4>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% }); %>
    </div>
</div>

<% include partials/footer %>
```

The "thumbnail" class is not working, I see the images all together like this:

[image]

What is wrong? Do I need to use older version of Bootstrap? Using 4.1.3 now

Comment: try img-thumbnail see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/images/#image-thumbnails.

Comment: Right answer! I think the tutorial es a bit outdate. How can I vote your answer as right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try img-thumbnail see getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/images/#image-thumbnails.

Comment: Right, the solution is <img src="<%= campground.image %>" class="img-thumbnail" >